# Como somar e armazenar quais foram as id somadas?

Tags: mysql, query

Boa tarde,
gostaria de saber se é possível realizar uma consulta somando alguns valores e criar uma coluna com as ids no qual os valores foram somados.

-- tabela 'valor'

| id | valor  | status |
| 1  | 100.00 |    0   |
| 2  | 200.00 |    1   |
| 3  | 300.00 |    0   |
| 4  | 400.00 |    1   |

-- sql

select sum(valor) as soma from valor V where V.status = 1

-- saída
|  soma   |
| 600.00  |

Porém gostaria que a saída ficasse assim.
-- saída desejada
|  soma   | ids  |
| 600.00  | 2,4  |

Como conseguiria fazer essa consulta?

Desde já.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente:

```
SELECT SUM(valor) AS soma, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids FROM valor V WHERE V.status = 1
```

Corrigido.

Comment: Funcionou!!!!! porém o comando é GROUP_CONCAT()... BRIGADÃO!!!